# Refrescar listado <List> después de borrar un item

Tags: java, android, xml, adapter

tengo el siguiente problema.

Necesito que al borrar un elemento de un List, se me refresque el adaptador que los contiene, pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar.

Así lo tengo montado:

**Main.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">

    <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/parent_layoutNew"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
          android:dividerHeight="8dp"
    />
</ScrollView>
```

**Main.java**

```
private List<Notifications> notificationsList = new ArrayList<>();
private AdapterOpenCard adapterOpenCard;


adapterOpenCard = new AdapterOpenCard(getContext(), notificationsList);

        for (int i = 0; i < notificationsList.size(); i++) {
            View item = adapterOpenCard.getView(i, null, parentLayout);
            parentLayout.addView(item);

            int position = i;

            item.setOnClickListener(view -> {

                if(notificationsList.get(position) == null){

                    notificationsList.remove(position); // Esto funciona

                    adapterOpenCard.notifyDataSetChanged();  // Esto no refresca

                }else{
                    // Otra cosa
                }
            });
        }
```

**adapterOpenCard.java**

```
public class AdapterOpenCard extends BaseAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private final Context context;
    private List<HomeInfo.Notifications> notifications;   

    public AdapterOpenCard(Context context, List<HomeInfo.Notifications> notifications){
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.notifications = notifications;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.notifications.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.notifications.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        final AdapterOpenCard.ViewHolder holder;
        HomeInfo.Notifications notifications1 = notifications.get(position);

        if(view==null){

            holder = new AdapterOpenCard.ViewHolder();
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_card_base, null);
            holder.txtTitulo = view.findViewById(R.id.titleCardBase);
            holder.txtMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.subTitleCardBase);

view.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (AdapterOpenCard.ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtTitulo.setText(notifications1.title());
        holder.txtMessage.setText(notifications1.message());

return view;
    }

  private static class ViewHolder{        
        private TextView txtTitulo;
        private TextView txtMessage;
}
}
```

Es decir, el listado carga bien en el adaptador. Sin errores, ni problemas.
Pero cuando quiero borrar un elemento de la lista, se borra bien, pero el notifyDataSetChanged(); no "refresca" el listado.

He intentado hacer que en lugar de usar LinearLayout para generar el listado, utilizar un ListView. Con eso sí me funciona bien, es decir, borra y refresca el listado sin problema. Pero el problema del listView es que el contenedor prinicpal es un ScrollView, y no me funciona bien la vista. Y el caso es que no puedo prescindir del Scroll, porque además del Listview hay otros elementos a mostrar.

Alguna sugerencia? Gracias!

Comment: Agregué una respesta pero agrega tu adapter por favor.

Comment: Gracias, acabo de añadir el adapter a mi pregunta.

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta de acuerdo a la información de tu adapter, trata lo que comento @Mimmetico

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás removiendo elementos en tu lista `notificationsList`, pero el `Adapter` tiene otra lista, la cual no está siendo modificada.

Agrega un método a tu adapter `adapterOpenCard.java` para actualizar el `list`, envías el `List` modificado e incluso aquí puedes llamar `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
   public void actualiza(List<HomeInfo.Notifications> notifications) {
        this.notifications;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

o también puedes llamar después a `adapterOpenCard.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys. He añadido una respuesta al hilo implementando la opción que mencionas, pero no me ha terminado de funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la respuesta Jorgesys. Pero no me termina de funcionar, o no sé si lo estoy aplicando correctamente.

En el **adapter** he creado el método que mencionas, así:

```
   public void actualiza(List<HomeInfo.Notifications> notifications) {
        this.notifications = notifications;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Y en el **main**, después de borrar un elemento de la lista, llamo a ese método pasándole la lista. Así lo he hecho:

```
notificationsList.remove(position);

adapterOpenCard.actualiza(notificationsList);
//adapterOpenCard.notifyDataSetChanged(); <--He probado aquí y en el adapter.
//adapterOpenCard = new AdapterOpenCard(getContext(), notificationsList);  <--también he probado pasándole así la lista actualiza y llamando al actualiza() al acceder al adapter, pero no va.
```

Pero me sigue sin funcionar.
No sé si estoy aplicando bien la lógica que has mencionado, o me estoy equivocando en algo.

Comment: Hola, ya probaste con esto:
adapterOpenCard.notifyItemRemoved(position);